# Помогите решить задачу и по возможности исправить мое решение

Tags: c#, .net, строки

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string ish = Console.ReadLine();
            char[] Road = ish.ToCharArray();

            int N = 0 , S = 0, W= 0, E = 0;

            int CCount = 0;
            while (CCount < Road.Length)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(Road[CCount + 1]) =="N")
                {
                    N += Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Road[CCount]));
                }
                if (Convert.ToString(Road[CCount + 1]) == "S")
                {
                    S += Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Road[CCount]));
                }
                if (Convert.ToString(Road[CCount + 1]) == "W")
                {
                    W += Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Road[CCount]));
                }
                if (Convert.ToString(Road[CCount + 1]) == "E")
                {
                    E += Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Road[CCount]));
                }

                CCount += 2;
            }


            List<roadlean> road = new List<roadlean>(4);

            var ones = new roadlean
            {
                Count = N,
                Type = "N",
            };
            road.Add(ones);

            var sec = new roadlean
            {
                Count = S,
                Type = "S",
            };
            road.Add(sec);

            var th = new roadlean
            {
                Count = W,
                Type = "W",
            };
            road.Add(th);

            var frt = new roadlean
            {
                Count = E,
                Type = "E",
            };
            road.Add(frt);






            string answer = "";
            if (Math.Max(road[0].Count,road[1].Count) - Math.Min(road[0].Count, road[1].Count) != 0)
            {
                string Name = road[0].Count > road[1].Count ? "N" : "S";
                 answer += Convert.ToString(Math.Max(road[0].Count, road[1].Count) - Math.Min(road[0].Count, road[1].Count)) + Name;
            }
            if (Math.Max(road[2].Count, road[3].Count) - Math.Min(road[2].Count, road[3].Count) != 0)
            {
                string Name = road[2].Count > road[3].Count ? "W" : "E";
                answer += Convert.ToString(Math.Max(road[2].Count, road[3].Count) - Math.Min(road[2].Count, road[3].Count)) + Name;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", answer);
            Console.ReadKey();

    }
        class roadlean
        {
            public int Count { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Мое решение мне определенно не нравится и не может обрабатывать числа превышающие 9, буду рад любой помощи, но только на C#
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не сильно вникал в ваше решение, просто подумал, как бы сам решал такую задачку. У меня получилось следующее

```
public string Shorter(string input)
{
    int dx = 0;
    int dy = 0; 
    int ind = 0; 

    while(ind < input.Length)
    {
        var start = ind; 
        var end = ind; 
        while(char.IsDigit(input[end])) end++;      
        var number = int.Parse(input.Substring(start, end-start));  
        var c = input[end];

        if (c == 'N') dy-=number;
        if (c == 'S') dy += number;
        if (c == 'W') dx -= number;
        if (c == 'E') dx += number;
        ind = end+1;
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (dx < 0) sb.Append($"{-dx}W");
    if (dx > 0) sb.Append($"{dx}E");
    if (dy < 0) sb.Append($"{-dy}N");
    if (dy > 0) sb.Append($"{dy}S");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Тестировал вот так

```
Console.WriteLine(Shorter("7N5E2S3E"));
Console.WriteLine(Shorter("10N30W20N"));
```

Получил на выходе

```
8E5N
30W30N
```